# Как программно на java скачать любое изображение по ссылке

Tags: java

Возникла проблема со скачиванием изображений с некоторых сайтов. Использую следующий метод для скачивания изображений

```
    public void downloadImageTest(){
    try {
        URLConnection openConnection = new URL("http://bloknot-volgograd.ru/thumb/800x0xcut/upload/iblock/0d0/serp3.jpeg").openConnection();
        openConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
        BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(openConnection.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        File file=new File("/tmp/out123.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(image1, "jpg", file);
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int j=0;
}
```

метод рабочий, с большинства ресурсов изображения скачиваются без проблем. Но встречаются такие ресурсы(как в примере), где при использовании данного метода я получаю image1=null. Помогите разобраться, в чем проблема? То ли изображение каким-то образом программно защищено от скачивания, то ли я что-то не учёл. Продублирую пример ссылки, с которой не могу скачать программно изображение

```
http://bloknot-volgograd.ru/thumb/800x0xcut/upload/iblock/0d0/serp3.jpeg
```

И в общем, с этого ресурса не могу скачать программно изображения, хотя раньше скачивал без проблем.

Comment: К сертификату сайта не хватает промежуточного сертификата, вот джава и не может проверить подлинность сайта. Обратитесь к администратору сайта, чтобы он починил свой сайт

Comment: @andreymal, иных путей решения нет? Скажем, как-то отключить эту проверку я не могу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если открыть вашу ссылку в браузере то картинка загрузится, однако в адресной строке вы увидите **https**://bloknot-volgograd.ru/thumb/800x0xcut/upload/iblock/0d0/serp3.jpeg

Ваш код рабочий и вы можете продолжать его использовать, просто нужно быть более внимательным к протоколу который используется со стороны сайта. Ну или вы можете улучшить свой парсер который сначала проверит изображение по http, а потом уже по https если например получит null.

Вот код который работает с https (первая часть просто игнорит проверку сертификатов):

```
 public static loadImage()
    {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new X509Certificate[0];
                    }
                    public void checkClientTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                    public void checkServerTrusted(
                            java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
                    }
                }
        };

// Install the all-trusting trust manager
        try {
            SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
        }

        URLConnection openConnection = new URL("https://bloknot-volgograd.ru/thumb/800x0xcut/upload/iblock/0d0/serp3.jpeg").openConnection();
        openConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0");
        BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(openConnection.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.out.println(image1);

    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я действительно не обратил внимание, что в браузере ссылка меняется на https. Остался вопрос, мой код отрабатывает, если поменять http на https, в чем преимущество Вашего кода? Ведь я просто могу менять http на https, если получаю image=null

Comment: Его нет, если у вас и так все работает :) Бывает что при работе с https вы можете получить exception связанные с SSL и мой код позволяет это избежать. В идеале конечно не просто игнорить сертификат, а работать через хранилище, но это уже другая история - вы можете погуглить если хотите.